# How to include variables inside a php file created via fopen

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a php file with the fopen() function. The content of the php file(s) that will be created need to be built so that they can be executed at a later date to update a mysql db. So if the php file is created, it should show include to a config.php and a way to connect to the db and execute a query.

So for example, the file that will be created will look something like:

```
<?php 
include_once 'config.php';
$updateSQL = "update table set is_active = 1 where id = 10";
$conn = mysqli_connect("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass","$usedb");
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());

} else {
mysqli_query($conn,$updateSQL );
}

?>
```

Creating an empty php file is simple but I don't know whether it is possible to show variables in the file that will be created.
FYI, the file will consist of other tasks such as creating a directory which I can do, this is the part I am stuck on so any suggestions?

Comment: you are playing with fire

Comment: fopen — Opens file or URL
$txt = "Hi Amar\n";
fwrite($filename, $txt); //to write data from mysql db (example)

Comment: This is usually a **super bad idea** and it's strongly recommended you find an alternative. Any alternative. Remember, MySQL can be coached to read in `.sql` files full of statements (still risky) or CSV-type delimited files (less risky). Running arbitrary PHP code is full of risks.

Comment: This will only be for internal use just to set a post to active. It can be done manually but I was looking for a way so I do not need to go into the db just  to find the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this my solve your query

```
 <?php
    $text = "hi Amar";
    $var_str = var_export($text, true);
    echo $var = "\n\n\$text = $var_str;\n\n";
  ?>
```

Result: **$text = 'hi Amar';**